# Giving access to localhost PHP to execute external programs (like Brackets) - Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, apache, shell, shell-exec

I'm trying to find ways to allow some local automation on my Mac (OS X Yosemite) through the use of running PHP on localhost (so that I can easily throw together a simple GUI for whatever it is I'm automating).

The problem is getting shell commands to work *with the appropriate access*... Here's where I started:

1. Make a duplicate of "/etc/php.ini.default" and rename it to "/etc/php.ini"
2. Add "safe_mode = Off" to php.ini file
3. Restart localhost - "sudo apachectl restart"

After that, I can get this test code to work and print results in a PHP page:

```
$result = shell_exec('ls');
echo $result;
```

Now what I want to be able to do is open files with an editor program ([Brackets](http://brackets.io)). I can do this in terminal by using this command:

```
brackets /Users/myusername/mypath/myfile.html
```

That... works in terminal but in a php script, this *doesn't* work:

```
$result = shell_exec('brackets /Users/myusername/mypath/myfile.html');
echo $result;
```

I'm assuming this is a user or permission issue? I don't get any sort of output or error. I know that locahost runs with the "_www" user and group. I tried changing this in /etc/apache2/httpd.chmod by changing "_www" to "myusername", but then php files no longer work in Safari after that.

Anyways, I feel like I'm close, but I don't know what to try next! I appreciate any answers :) (Also I'm well aware that this is a bit of a security downgrade, but I don't mind since this is strictly local and not public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. Go to the command line and type `sudo visudo`. This will open up vim (look up how to use vim if you don't know how) so that you can edit your sudoers file, which is what controls who can use `sudo` to get permissions to do what. I have done this on an Ubuntu machine to give PHP access to etherwake. This is my sudoers file for it:

```
User_Alias      PHP_USER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias      ETHERWAKE = /usr/sbin/etherwake
PHP_USER        ALL = NOPASSWD: ETHERWAKE
```

Just switch www-data to the name of the PHP user on your computer.

I believe you can specify ALL rather than a `Cmnd_Alias` like `ETHERWAKE` to give access to all commands but BE WARNED: THAT IS AN EXTREMELY DANGEROUS THING TO DO. It is MUCH safer to give it access to specific commands, otherwise anyone that could authenticate themselves as that user on their computer could do ANYTHING.

Any command that PHP needs to run as an administrator should start with `sudo`. Ex:

```
$result = shell_exec('sudo ls');
```